# Postgres - Update column with number of occurences of an array element

Tags: postgresql

i am wondering if anyone could help me with updating a table in postgres. the table has two columns - one is players, and other is goals scored. 
i have a list (array that comes from the app) which contains names of scorers. the names can be repeated - this indicates how many goals the player scored. 
so i need to insert number of player name occurences in the list into the column goals scored, and make sure those goals match the name of the player in the players column. 
i tried creating temp table to test selecting it. i was thinking cardinality of array that contains specific player name where player name is in the list, but the problem is that the specific player name (user4 in this case) is hardcoded, and i would like to have it dynamic, to have the same value as the current iteration of list of values in the where clause (i assume there is some kind of iteration happening in where clause, i am super new to postgres).

```
...
select cardinality
   (array_positions(array['user3', 'user3', 'user4','user4','user4'], 'user4'))
where
    players in ('user3', 'user4')
...
```

here is an image to illustrate the problem
so goals scored column needs to have entries (top to bottom) : 2, 3, 2, 1

[image: update dable with goals scored illustration]

Comment: The data supplied is inconsistent with indicated results (problem) image. Please post sample data as text - no images - and the result you expect from that data. It may be good for you to review [ask].

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unnest` function to convert the array to a table and count the number of occurrences of each player:

```
SELECT player,
       count(*) AS goals
FROM unnest(ARRAY['user3', 'user3', 'user4', 'user4', 'user4']) AS player
GROUP BY player;

 player | goals 
--------+-------
 user3  |     2
 user4  |     3
(2 rows)
```

You can then insert that into a table with

```
INSERT INTO goals_table (player, goals)
SELECT /* the query from above */
```